# How to set focus on a checkbox in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am working over a form that displays a table with first column as checkbox. User is supposed to select at least one checkbox. I want to highlight the check boxes while I submit the form as they need to be selected. Below is my checkbox code -

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let account">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    (change)="$event ? datalist.toggle(account) : null"  
   [checked]="datalist.isSelected(account)"                                                  
    formControlName="checkbox" required>
     </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

I tried searching for focus attribute but didn't get any proper example over it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add focus to checkbox you have to use ViewChild decorator to get the ref to check box

```
@ViewChild('ref') ref:ElementRef;
```

Then add Focus method to focus the element on Click

```
 onClick(){
  this.ref.focus();
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-focus

Comment: Hi, it does work but it gives following error -   Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>. Also it only highlights the first checkbox. I am in a need where it highlights all the checkbox in first column so that user knows that it needs to select an checkbox.

Comment: I believe that the correct syntax would be this.ref.nativeElement.focus();

Comment: I Have tried that but that does not work! check the stackblitz @MagnusWallström

Comment: @ViewChild('ref') ref; works without error.
ElementRef; is not needed

Comment: Acutally adding that will give better typesafety @ab.dev

Answer (score 0):

### The .focus() way

Inside your component.html use a reference to set focus:

```
<mat-checkbox #checkboxRef></mat-checkbox>
```

Inside your component.ts use @ViewChild as follows:

```
@ViewChild('checkboxRef', {static: false}) checkTerms: { focus: () => any; };
```

Then you can set focus with:

```
setTimeout(() => this.checkboxRef.focus());
```

This is the way you can set focus as focus is conceibed.

---

### The ng-class way

To create a class to highlight empty or certain checboxes and change the class with ng-Class you can use on each mat-checkbox:

```
ng-class="{active : isChecked}
```

Then, in the css, change the respective class. In this case, *active*:

```
.active { box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888; }
```

This is considering you have a default shadow with the checkboxes highlighted.